# Work with SD card in WorkLight framework and browser emulator

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, geotagging

I am trying to write a Worklight Hybrid application that requires reading image files saved on the device's SD card.

The application needs to read the metadata of the images - in particular the GeoTag data. I am familiar with the PhoneGap API that allows access to files on the SD card, but I have difficulty reading the GeoTag data.

I am also desperately looking for a way to push image files to Worklight Console MBS (Mobile Browser Simulator), so I can test my application using the browser emulator as well.

Answer (score 2):

The Geolocation data is contained in the Exif metadata in the image.  Reading the Geolocation data from Cordova captured images may not work for Cordova versions prior to 2.6, as there were a number of resolved issues for Exif in Cordova 2.6.  As mentioned, the most recent Worklight version 5.0.6.1 contains Cordova 2.3.

For Android devices, there was a resolved issue related to Exif in Cordova 2.6. Here is the link to the issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1700

For iOS devices, the ability to write the Exif data to captured images was added in Cordova 2.6.  However, it does not include Geolocation data.  There is an open issue for Exif Geolocation data that is targeted for the Cordova 2.8 release.  Here is the link:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2905

Answer (score 0):

In Cordova 2.6 an issue has been fixed that address retrieving EXIF data from images. I think that without it, it won't be possible.

The latest Worklight, v5.0.6.1 is using Cordova 2.3; 2.6 is scheduled to be included in the next release of Worklight.

See [CB-1285 Include EXIF metadata in image upload](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1285).